# traversing JSON using a variable

Tags: javascript, json, traversal

I am trying to traverse a JSON file using a variable that gets set earlier in my script.

Example of the JSON:

```
{
    "page1": [{
        "template": "temp1",
        "other": "example"
    }],
    "page2": [{
        "template": "temp2",
        "other": "example"
    }],
    "page3": [{
        "template": "temp3",
        "other": "example"
    }]
}
```

The variable can be one of three items... page1, page2, page3

As I said I am setting the variable further up in the code so say the variable is:

```
var getid = "page1";
```

What I want to do is, if the variable is "page1", then get the "template" value of "temp1".

my console.log

```
console.log(json[getid]);
```

returns

```
[{template: "temp1"}]
```

but I don't really know how to go any further. Everything I try returns "undefined" or an error.

As I said, I want to get "temp1" in this example.

Can anyone help me along?

If you need more info, please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: `json[getid][0]["template"]`

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var json = {
    "page1": [{
        "template": "temp1",
        "other": "example"
    }],
    "page2": [{
        "template": "temp2",
        "other": "example"
    }],
    "page3": [{
        "template": "temp3",
        "other": "example"
    }]
};

var getid = "page1";

console.log(json[getid][0].template);
```

you are very close to the solution, just access object inside array you are done.

```
json[getid][0].template
```

will do

Comment: That worked great...yup so close. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. `json[getid]` return an `array` of one `object` So you need to access the first item of array using `[0]` which will return object object and then use `.template`

```js
let json = {
    "page1": [{
        "template": "temp1",
        "other": "example"
    }],
    "page2": [{
        "template": "temp2",
        "other": "example"
    }],
    "page3": [{
        "template": "temp3",
        "other": "example"
    }]
}
var getid = "page1";
console.log(json[getid][0].template);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.